# Filtering in Android - issue that the code works but it doesn't return to the screen as expected

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've created an app in Android to retrieve restaurants in the local area and return them in list view. I've created individual arrays for each of the details in question (name / address / postcode & hygiene rating). Some of the venues are exempt and the array will return the information as -1, so I want to alter this using a filter, which I think I have done.

This is my Async Task which returns the JSON array.

```
// lets things run in the background, JSON Array to retrieve the list
class RetrieveNearestRestaurantsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {

    private Exception exception;

    // performs the search in the background / populates the arraylist
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // if the searchUrl conversion is empty
        if (!searchUrl.toString().isEmpty()) {
            // do this instead
            try {
                URL url = new URL(searchUrl.toString());
                URLConnection tc = url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String line;  // variable

                // while line in (read in) is not equal to null
                // create a new object and output as line in JSON
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    ja = new JSONArray(line);

                    // run through the length of the array

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);

                        // output to meet Basic Functionality requirement
                        businessNames.add(JO.getString("BusinessName"));
                        postCodes.add(JO.getString("PostCode"));
                        addressList1.add(JO.getString("AddressLine1"));
                        addressList2.add(JO.getString("AddressLine2"));
                        addressList3.add(JO.getString("AddressLine3"));

                        // if the rating of the restaurant is -1, exempt
                        // should be displayed
                        ratingValue.add(JO.getString("RatingValue"));
                        ratingValue.stream()
                                .filter(x -> x.equals("-1"))
                                .findFirst()
                                .ifPresent(v -> System.out.println("Exempt"));
                        calcDistance.add(JO.getString("DistanceKM"));
                        // output everything together
                        ConcatenateSearchResults();
                    }
                }
                isr.close();
                in.close();
                //return ja;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;

                return ja;
            } finally {
                //is.close();
            }
        }
        return ja;
    }
```

Loads the search results.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            LoadSearchResults();
            }
    }
```

Concatenates the search results

```
    private ArrayList<String> ConcatenateSearchResults()
    {
        int length = businessNames.size();
        ArrayList<String> concatenatedResults = new ArrayList<>();

        if(!businessNames.isEmpty() && !calcDistance.isEmpty() && !ratingValue.isEmpty()
                && !addressList1.isEmpty() && !addressList2.isEmpty() && !addressList3.isEmpty()
                && !postCodes.isEmpty())
        {
            for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
            {
                concatenatedResults.add("\n"+businessNames.get(i) +
                        "\nDistance (in Km) :"+ calcDistance.get(i) +
                        "\n\nRating: "+ ratingValue.get(i) +
                        "\nAddress Line 1: "+ addressList1.get(i) +
                        "\nAddress Line 2: "+ addressList2.get(i)+
                        "\nAddress Line 3: "+ addressList3.get(i) +
                        "\nPostcode: "+ postCodes.get(i));
            }
        }
        return concatenatedResults;
    }
}
```

However, I think somewhere I haven't enabled the proper ratingValue variable (?) to return the correct information (exempt instead of -1, where applicable, but I haven't worked out what I might have done wrong. Thank you for any help, I am slooowly getting better at explaining what I don't know.

Comment: Do you use breakpoints?

Comment: I haven't no, I'm very new to this. It returns complete information to the screen, however all the -1 remain in the returned list, so I guess the code is somehow by-passing the filter but I'm not sure how, or maybe it is filtering them, but not storing (?) them and continues to return -1. I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: anyone? I know what the problem is - but I'm not sure how to solve